# How can I concatenate a String with a Bit (documentTitle+Archive) SQL server 2005

Tags: sql-server, string, bit, concatenation

I get the following error when I try to concatenate
Operand type clash: text in incompatible with bit
Invalid operator for datatype: Operator equals Add, Type equal bit

```
SELECT
  F.SubmissionId, F.FormId, 
  F.DocumentTitle + F.Archive AS DocumentTitle,
  F.Keywords, F.PublishDate, F.PostedDate, F.ExpiredDate, 
  F.IsFlag, F.IsAdminOnly, F.IsCompleted, F.IsPublished,
  F.CreatedDate, F.AllowComments, 
  CASE WHEN F.Archive = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS Archive, 
  I.ItemId, I.SubmissionId AS Expr1, I.ParamId, I.ParamValue
FROM
  dbo.app_FormSubmission AS F
    INNER JOIN dbo.app_FormSubmissionItems AS I ON 
      F.SubmissionId = I.SubmissionId
```

Comment: What do you expect to see as a result of "F.DocumentTitle + F.Archive AS DocumentTitle"?

Answer (score 7):

you need to convert, run this to see what I mean

```
declare @i bit
select @i = 1

select 'abc'  + convert(varchar(1),@i) -- fine
select 'abc'  + @i  -- will fail
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you do it in the presentation layer whatever it might be in your case?

If it's not an option, then here's what I would do. First, I'd check whether *case* statement works as expected and if it does, I'd use *concat* SQL function to concatenate strings.

And make sure that when using F.Archive in F.DocumentTitle + F.Archive you're actually referring to the result of your *case* clause, not to the original column.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this to make it work. Thanks SQLMenace

SELECT     CONVERT(varchar(50), F.DocumentTitle) + CONVERT(varchar(1), F.Archive) AS Expr1